# R datatable weekday not defined because of singularities

Tags: r, regression

I have a datatable (looking like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdt09.jpg , where I'd like to see how different weekdays affect stock prices. However, when I create use them `lm()` function and summary, I get an 'error':

Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities) with th row showing only NA's

The formula I used is `lm(formula = wd$ewretd ~ fr + mo + tu + we + th)`.

Is there any way to see all the days?

Comment: The problem here is statistical rather than programming, so is on-topic here. However I wonder if this is a duplicate of an existing question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your dataset only contains weekdays Monday through Friday, your weekday dummies are collinear with the intercept. You can suppress the intercept using `-1`, that is, `lm(formula = wd$ewretd ~ fr + mo + tu + we + th -1)`

Alternatively, encode the day of week in a `factor` and then include this factor as an IV. Then R will take care of all dummy encoding automatically.